# Update records by joining local and foreign db using db link

Tags: sql-update, postgresql-9.6, dblink, postgresql-12

1. `t` - current db table
2. `table1` - other db
3. `database` - current db table where the "other db" credentials are stored

````
SELECT 
    t.*
FROM "database" d, t, 
    dblink_exec(
        format('dbname = %s host = %s port = %s user = %s password = %s', databasename, servername, port, username, "password"),
               format('UPDATE 
                            table1 a 
                       SET 
                           (col1, col2) = (SELECT
                                                %L :: json, now() 
                                           FROM t b -- t is the local table (from current db) 
                                           WHERE b.col2 = a.col2 
                                               AND b.col3 = a.col3 
                                               AND b.col4 = a.col4)
                       WHERE a.col2 = ''ABC''
                            AND a.col3 = ''DEF''
                            ', data )) -- column data is from table ```t```
WHERE databasename = 'otherdb';
````

How to update the records by joining local table to other db. I need the table `t` to stick in the correct place. I can't run this on other db as there are other dependencies (mostly timing).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by JOINING the tables first and form the UPDATE statement and feed the UPDATE statement to the dblink_exec.

```
SELECT
    dblink_exec(
        format('dbname = %s host = %s port = %s user = %s password = %s', databasename, servername, port, username, "password"),
               format ('UPDATE table1 %1$sSET col4 = %3$L :: json, %2$scol3 = now() %1$sWHERE col3 = %4$L %2$sAND col3 = ''ABC'' %2$sAND col2 = ''DEF'';', 
                                E'\n',
                                E'\n\t',
                                t.data,
                                t.col3 
               )
    )
FROM t 
    INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT x.*
            FROM "database" d, 
                    dblink(
                            format('dbname = %s host = %s port = %s user = %s password = %s', 
                                                databasename, servername, port, username, "password"
                                    ),
                            'SELECT 
                                * 
                            FROM  table1 
                            WHERE  col1 = ''ABC'' 
                                 AND col2 = ''DEF''
                                 '   
                         ) AS x( col1 TEXT,
                                 col2 TEXT,
                                 col3 TEXT,
                                 col4 TEXT
                                ) 
            WHERE databasename = 'otherdb'
        ) as otherdb
    CROSS JOIN "database" d
        ON otherdb.col1 = t.col1
            AND otherdb.col2 = t.col2
            AND otherdb.col1 = 'DEF'
            AND otherdb.col2 = 'ABC'
WHERE databasename = 'otherdb';
```